# fsyms is a required param

Tags: reactjs

fetch запрос выдает ошибку

```
    const API_URL_SEARCH = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull'

    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch(API_URL_SEARCH, {
            params: {
                fsym: 'BTC',
                tsym: 'USD',
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error.message)
        })
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал это таким способом:

```
const API_URL_SEARCH = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull';

const fetchData = () => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();

  params.append('fsyms', 'CAKE');
  params.append('tsyms', 'USD');

  return fetch(`${API_URL_SEARCH}?${params}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
};
```